# Python bytes object from generator

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, generator

Let's say I have a generator like

```
gen = (i*2 for i in range(100))
```

and I now want to create a bytes object containing all the values that generator yields. I could do the following:

```
b = bytes(gen)
```

My question now is: since `bytes` objects are immutable, how does the memory allocation work in this case? Do I have to assume that for every element the generator yields, there is a new `bytes` object created, with the previous content plus another element copied into it? This would be very inefficient especially for generators of bigger lenghts. And since the generator does not provide any length information, it seems there wouldn't be any other way of pre-allocating the needed memory internally.

Then again, what would be a better way to achieve this, with as few as possible memory usage? If I used a (mutable) `bytearray` first and casted that into a `bytes` object?

```
b = bytes(bytearray(gen))
```

Or even a list?

```
b = bytes(list(gen))
```

But that looks somehow strange and counter-intuitive...

---

Background: The specific generator I have reads bytes (as Python integers in 0..255) one at a time over a C-API from another module (.pyd), and the overall length of the sequence is already known beforehand, with up to 2**25 bytes in there. My readout function should collect those and return a `bytes` object, which I thought was appropriate, since the data is read only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bytes(iterator)` create bytes object from iterator using internal C-API `_PyBytes_FromIterator` function, which use special `_PyBytes_Writer` protocol. It internaly use a buffer, which resize when it overflows using a rule:

```
bufsize += bufsize  / OVERALLOCATE_FACTOR
```

For linux OVERALLOCATE_FACTOR=4, for windows OVERALLOCATE_FACTOR=2.

Those. This process looks like writing to a file in RAM. At the end, the contents of the buffer returns.

Answer (score 2):

this is probably more a remark or discussion start than an answer but I think it's better to format it like this.
I just hooking in 'cause I find this topic very inteeresting as well.

I would recommend to paste the real call and generator mock. Since imho the generator expression example does not fit really well for your question.
And the example code you pasted does not work.

Normally you have a generator like this: (in your case calling the module instead of generating numbers of course ..)
Example slightly modified from [dabeaz](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf)
**Update: deleted the explicit byte creatinon.**

```
def genbytes():
    for i in range(100):
         yield i**2
```

You would the probably call it with something like this:

```
for newbyte in genbytes():
    print(newbyte)
    print(id(newbyte))
    input("press key...")
```

leeds to:

> Do I have to assume that for every element the generator yields, there
>   is a new bytes object created

I would say absolutely yes. That's the way that yield works. And what we can see above. Bytes always has a new id.

Normally this shouldn't be a problem since you want to consume the bytes one by one and then collect it into something like you suggested a `bytearray` using `bytearray append`

But even if new bytes are produced I think this is at least not producing 33 MB in the input at once and returning them.

I add this exerpt from [PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) where the equivalence of a gen expression and the generator in "function" style is pointed out:

> The semantics of a generator expression are equivalent to creating an
>   anonymous generator function and calling it. For example:

```
g = (x**2 for x in range(10))
print g.next()
```

is equivalent to:

```
def __gen(exp):
    for x in exp:
        yield x**2
g = __gen(iter(range(10)))
print g.next()
```

So `bytes(gen)` also calls `gen.next()` (which `yields` ints in this case but probably bytes in your real case) while itrerating over the `gen`.

Comment: My example works in Python 3 only, using the round brackets around list comprehension to create a generator iterator. Looking at your `print`, you tried it in Python 2 ;)

Comment: Your generator creates and yields a new `bytes` object every time, so of course the `id` is different then, you explicitly made it so. In contrast, I only do the call to `bytes`' constructor once, presuming that internally this might lead to further (implicit) calls to it. That's not quite the same...

Comment: I just made a type in the exampole. I am using pyhton 3.6 ... I change that

Comment: True. But as I understood you the generator expression is just an example. IN reality you are calling a function that yields something. The gen expression does that, too. It's just a convenience function. So normally you would have to iterate over the yielded vals...

Comment: The function returns byte values (as Python integers in 0..255) and takes an offset argument. So I thought I could loop over the offsets within the (known) length of the buffer, get all the bytes and put them together into a bytes object. Looks something like `bytes(func(i) for i in range(buf_len))`.

Answer (score 2):

Creating immutable types from arbitrary sized iterables is a common task for Python. Most notably, `tuple` is an ubiquitous immutable type. This makes it a necessity to *efficiently* create such instances – constantly creating and discarding intermediate instances would not be efficient.

Using a generator as the source of `bytes` will be reasonably fast. However, directly providing data as a fixed `tuple` or `list` would be faster, and a [readable buffer](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) can even be directly copied to a new `bytes` object. If the data is provided as a generator, intermediate `tuple`, `list` or `bytearray` will not offer a benefit.

---

The general task of creating a fixed size instance from an iterable is not unique to immutable types. Even a mutable type such as `list` has a fixed size at any specific point in time. While filling a `list` by `.append`ing elements during iteration, Python cannot know the final size ahead of time.
Looking at the size of a `list` in such a scenario reveals the general strategy of turning an arbitrary size iterable into a specific sized container:

```py
>>> items = []
>>> for i in (i*2 for i in range(10)):
>>>     items.append(i)
>>>     print(i // 2, "\t", sys.getsizeof(items))
0    88
1    88
2    88
3    88
4    120
5    120
6    120
7    120
8    184
9    184
```

As can be seen, Python does not grow the `list` for each item. Instead, when the `list` is too small an entire chunk of space is added that can hold *several* items before resizing is required again.

A naive implementation of `bytes` when presented with an arbitrary sized iterable would first convert its argument to a `list`, then copy the content to a new `bytes` instance. This would already *create only one `bytes` instance* and one temporary, auxiliary `list` – much more efficient than creating a new instance per element.

---

However, it is possible to go one step further: `bytes` is an immutable sequence of immutable integers, so it does not have to preserve the identity of its items: since the value of each `bytes` item fits exactly into a byte / C `char`, the items can be written directly to memory.
In the [CPython 3.9 implementation, constructing `bytes` from iterables](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f26fec4f74ae7da972595703bc39d3d30b8cfdf9/Objects/bytesobject.c#L2804-L2845) has some special cases for *direct access buffers*, guaranteed-size *`list` and `tuple`*, and a generic path for *any* other iterable that is not a string. The case of a generator also falls into the latter path.

[This generic path](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Objects/bytesobject.c#L2742-L2802) uses [a `struct` as a primitive, low-level "list" for `char`s](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Include/cpython/bytesobject.h#L44-L65) – it uses a `char` array for storage, and holds metadata like current and maximum size. The byte value of wach item fetched from the iterable/generator is simply copied directly to the current end of the `char` array; if the `char` array becomes too small, it is replaced by a new, larger `char` array. Once the iterable/generator is exhausted, the `char` array can be directly used as the internal storage of the new `bytes` object.

---

When looking at the timings, the important part is whether the data already comes from a generator, or whether one can chose other formats.

When there already is a generator, feeding it directly to `bytes` is the fastest – though not by much.

```
%timeit bytes(i*2 % 256 for i in range(2**20))
107 ms ± 411 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit bytes(bytearray(i*2 % 256 for i in range(2**20)))
111 ms ± 946 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit bytes(tuple(i*2 % 256 for i in range(2**20)))
114 ms ± 1.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit bytes(list(i*2 % 256 for i in range(2**20)))
115 ms ± 741 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

However, if the initial data structure can be freely chosen, a `list` is faster at the cost of intermediate storage.

```py
%timeit bytes([i*2 % 256 for i in range(2**20)])
94.5 ms ± 1.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

When directly creating the data in a C/Cython module, providing a `bytes`/`bytesarray` is by far fastest and has low overhead.